# Split arguments like shlex.split but convert environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, shlex

I want to split a string into command-line arguments, exactly like shlex.split does. However, shlex doesn't seem to convert environment variables (for example `$USER`), and the output makes it impossible to know whether the environment variable was escaped:

```
>>> print(shlex.split("My name is Alice"))
['My', 'name', 'is', 'Alice']
>>> print(shlex.split("My name is '$USER'"))
['My', 'name', 'is', '$USER']
>>> print(shlex.split("My name is $USER")) # expected Alice, not $USER
['My', 'name', 'is', '$USER']
```

Is there a way to achieve this? (hopefully without re-implementing the whole thing)

Also, why doesn't shlex.split do this by default in the first place?

If it matters, I am using Python 3.6.8.

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed into [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) is a *string*.

You will have to retrieve the environment variable, using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), and then concatenate it into the string, e.g.

```
import shlex
import os
print(shlex.split(f"My name is {os.environ['USER']}"))
# ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Alice']
```

If your input string is coming from a file, then you can evaluate the environment variables using [`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

```
import shlex
import os
print(shlex.split(os.path.expandvars("My name is $USER")))
# ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Alice']
```

If you need to account for escaped variables in the string, you can send the string off to `echo` in the shell using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with `shell` set to `True`.

This version will work in all three cases in your situation. It works regardless of how the variable is escape, e.g. slash-escaped or using quotes.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

strings = [
    "My name is Alice",
    "My name is '$USER'",
    "My name is \$USER",
    "My name is $USER"
]

for s in strings:
    split = subprocess.run(f'echo {s}', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(shlex.split(split.stdout.decode('utf-8')))
# ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Alice']
# ['My', 'name', 'is', '$USER']
# ['My', 'name', 'is', '$USER']
# ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Alice']
```

**WARNING:**

Setting `shell` to `True` is dangerous. Only do this if the input string is *trusted*.

For example, if the string was `"My name is $USER; rm file"`, then the file `file` would be removed.

Comment: The string was produced outside of Python (it will be read from a file), which is why the conversion will have to be made while parsing/splitting it.

Comment: this also expands vars that should be escaped (e.g. second example I gave, with `'$USER'`)

Comment: @neatnit check if the update above works for you

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid `shell=True` isn't a good idea at all in my case. It *would* work though.

Comment: You may have to do some parsing in such a case. Could be simplified if you know the format of the input (i.e. if it follows a consistent structure).

Comment: In the end I did use `os.path.expandvars` like you suggested - even though it's not quite as robust as I had hoped. It will almost definitely work in my case. Thanks for that! 

Still, I'm not sure if I can accept this answer as it doesn't tick all the boxes in my question.. What do you think?

Comment: Great, glad one of my suggestions helped.